# Rails plain text template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'd like to render an ERB template into plain text in Rails. Ideally, I'd be able to do something like this:

**app/views/test/test.txt.erb**

```
Test
<%= @test %>
```

When I tried, Rails complained with the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template test/test, application/test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/landonschropp/Development/test/app/views"
):
```

Comment: Why is your file name is `test.txt.erb`? isn't that supposed to be `test.html.erb`

Comment: I want to render it as plain text, not HTML.

Comment: I understood that you want to render it as a plain text,but there is no format called `txt`,so is the error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way is in your action:

```
render '/test/test.text.erb', layout: false, content_type: 'text/plain'
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok the way I found is to add

```
Mime::Type.register 'text/plain', :txt
```

to environment.rb

If you need you can add *defaults: {format: 'txt'}* option to route definition

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

  get 'test', to: 'pages#test', defaults: {format: 'txt'}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this didn't seem to work form me. I still received the same error as above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just render the file itself use:

```
render "/test/test.text.erb"
```

It's important to use the "/" in the beginning as rails discerns it's a file. Of course, it's not gonna escape the "<" or ">" from html tags.

Or if it's plain text not exactly from a file, you can inline it:

```
render plain: "OK"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this answer was missing the MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using...

```ruby
render 'test', layout: false, formats: [:text]
```

...generally works, assuming you have a template named `test.text.erb` in one of the normally searched locations under `/app/views`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simple text

```
 render :text => "write your text here"
```